# IIS Windows Server Rewrite rule get params QUERY_STRING

Tags: php7, iis, configuración, windows-server, rewriterule

Estoy intentando configurar la regla de reescritura de un framework front controller, pero no logro que los parametros queden en la variable QUERY_STRING. El framework recibe en esas variable las rutas y las matchea. QUERY_STRING siempre esta vacía, pero si me llegan los parametros por GET. Les dejo mi código

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO!

Solo modifique como pasa el parametro al index.php en la accion de la regla, modifiqué esto **index.php?q={R:1}** por esto **index.php?{R:1}**

El action queda así:

`<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />`

y toda la regla completa queda así:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Espero que ayude a alguien.